# *low level* messages in ROS (Indigo)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm beginner in ROS and I have a question about the messages in ROS.
Are there **low level messages** in ROS?
For example, if i want to move the robot to location (x,y), I need to send a MoveBaseGoal message. I want to know if there is a way to see messages that directly go to motor (if they exist)?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258471/*low-level*-messages-in-ros-(indigo)/) by [matansar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29912/matansar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most robots implement a `cmd_vel` topic with the `geometry_msgs/Twist` type which commands the linear and angular velocities of your mobile base. This isn't quite raw motor commands, but it's much closer to an actuator command.

Some robots perform the conversion from `cmd_vel` to raw motor commands in the driver node or on the embedded motor controller board, and some robots do the conversion to raw motors commands in a ROS nodes and publish additional topics that are then passed to the motor control node. You'll need to refer to the documentation for your specific robot to find out how it does this. (You may also be able to figure out by inspecting the list of topics when your robot is running)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matansar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29912/matansar/) on 2017-04-04**:
I have tried to find some documentation about my robot.
I works on Armadillo robot (robotican, Indigo). Do you know some links for documentation?
Thanks!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-04**:
A quick search on the ROS wiki finds http://wiki.ros.org/robotican_armadillo?distro=indigo and http://wiki.ros.org/robotican , and this tutorial for sending `cmd_vel`: http://wiki.ros.org/robotican/Tutorials/Command%20you%20robot%20with%20simple%20motion%20commands